# Como fazer InnerJoin com tabela relacionada?

Tags: doctrine-2

Pessoal tenho uma classe `Arquivo` que tem um relacionamento ManyToOne com uma classe `Usuario` funcionando certinho. Preciso listar todos os dados que estão na classe `Arquivo`s incluindo os relacionamentos. Como eu faço isso no Doctrine?

Relacionamento da classe Arquivo esta assim:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="JN\Entity\Usuarios\Usuario", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="usuario_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 **/
private $usuario;
```

Quando eu faço assim no doctrine não volto o conteúdo do relacionamento:

```
$ent = $this->em->getRepository( "JN\Entity\Arquivos\Arquivo" )
                ->createQueryBuilder('t')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monte sua query da seguinte maneira:

```
$ent = $this->em->getRepository("JN\Entity\Arquivos\Arquivo" )
    ->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->join('t.usuario', 'u')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

O resultado será uma coleção de entidades do tipo `JN\Entity\Arquivos\Arquivo`. Para iterar por essas entidades e pegar o usuário de cada arquivo faça assim:

```
foreach ($ent as $arquivo) {
    $arquivo->getUsuario();
}
```

Comment: Obrigadão deu certinho.